# Cannot load this JVM TI agent twice

Tags: tomcat, windows-services

Tomcat is installed as windows service. I want to attach a debugger to it. It fails to start when I add the related JVM options to command line:

```
d:\Projects\bin\tomcat\jira-it\bin>tomcat6.exe //TS//mysvc ++JvmOptions -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=0.0.0.0:8787,server=y,suspend=y
ERROR: Cannot load this JVM TI agent twice, check your java command line for duplicate jdwp options.
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: jdwp
```

Where else does tomcat service store its options? `catalina.bat` has nothing to do with it. I also didn't find anything in `conf` directory. There are no `CATALINA_*` or `JAVA_*` env. vars except `JAVA_HOME`

When started without my options tomcat prints a message:

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8003
```

But no file in `bin/` of `conf/` contain the word "8003"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tomcat stores its config in

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\<svcname>\Parameters\Java
```